# Juntar informações repetidas em uma linha da tabela PHP

Tags: php, html

Preciso juntar em uma linha da tabela quando os endereços se repetirem trazendo somente um endereço dos três que possuo, segue código abaixo:

```
                <table class="tableModif">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Romaneio</th>
                            <th>Placa</th>
                            <th>Cte</th>
                            <th>Data Saida</th>
                            <th>Endereço</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($roteiro->ListaRoteiro($romaneioIni, $romaneioFin, $dataIni, $dataFin, $empIni, $empFin) as $dados) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $dados->getRomaneio(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dados->getPlaca(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dados->getCte(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo ($roteiro->FormataData($dados->getDtSaidaRomaneio())); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dados->getEndereco(); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deveria ficar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Imagino que isso esteja vindo do banco né? não seria melhor você usar groupby na query?

Comment: Sim, séria mas gostaria de tratar no php mesmo.

Comment: O ideal era fazer uma query melhor mas se quer fazer no php, vai ter que  filtrar o resultado. Se as placas são o único campo que se repete, faça um foreach dentro de outro, pegando apenas a placa no laço interno e acrescentando no array como placa1, placa2, placa3 e assim por diante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guarde os dados que já saíram em um array, ou como @JuniorNunes disse em comentário, use `groupby`:

```
$repetidos = array();
foreach ($roteiro->ListaRoteiro($romaneioIni, $romaneioFin, $dataIni, $dataFin, $empIni, $empFin) as $dados) {
    $repetidos[$dados->getEndereco()]['romaneio'] = $dados->getRomaneio();
    $repetidos[$dados->getEndereco()]['placa'] = $dados->getPlaca();
    $repetidos[$dados->getEndereco()]['ctes'][] = $dados->getCte();
    $repetidos[$dados->getEndereco()]['data'] = $roteiro->FormataData($dados->getDtSaidaRomaneio());
    $repetidos[$dados->getEndereco()]['endereco'] = $dados->getEndereco();
}

...
<?php
foreach ($repetidos as $dados) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $dados['romaneiro']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dados['placa']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo implode(', ', $dados['ctes']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dados['data']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dados['endereco']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
...
```

Porque temos de guardar todos os `ctes` que uma determinada rua (endereco) pode ter, temos de fazer um loop e guardar todos os endereços antes, aqui todos os dados repetidos vão-se sobreescrevendo ex: `$repetidos[$dados->getEndereco()]['romaneio']`, ou seja com a chave `$dados->getEndereco()` que pode ser "rua 1" ficando `$repetidos['rua 1']['romaneio']`, por muitas "rua 1" que tivermos a unica coisa que vai acontecer é sobreescrever o resultado para 'romaneiro', 'placa' etc.... Isto vai acontecer para todos excepto para os ctes, esses de facto queremos guardar todos de uma determinada rua.

Não sei se expliquei bem, mas qualquer duvida pergunte sem problema

Comment: Mas dessa forma ele não conseguiria separar por vírgula o 3º item da tabela =/

Comment: Como? que virgula? @JuniorNunes

Comment: Observe na 2º imagem que ele colocou a 3º coluna. Ele agrupou o 8-33090, 8-30100, 8-30107

Comment: Ha certo @JuniorNunes . vou rever, erro meu

Comment: @Miguel Deu certo, só teria como explicar melhor o que foi feito ? Entendi que foi posto os dados em um array, mas aonde ele trata os repetidos ?

Comment: Ok, @Kevin.F , vou explicar na resposta